# Reduce resolution of Asus Xtion Pro Live

Tags: asus-xtion-pro-live, ubuntu, resolution, ubuntu-precise, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to change the resolution of my Asus Xtion Pro Live. I'm currently running ROS Groovy on Ubuntu 12.04.

I am aware that there is a graphical method to do this, using `rosrun rqt_reconfigure rqt_reconfigure`, but is there a command line way of doing this? Or even better, is there some way such that when I use `roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch`, the resolution is lowered by default? The default right now is VGA 640x480 @ 30fps. I want to change it to QVGA 320x240 @ 30fps.

I tried adding `<arg name="image_node" value="5" />` to my openni.launch file, but it didn't do anything. I set the value to 5 because using the graphical method, QVGA 320x240 @ 30fps is labelled as (5).

Can someone help me out here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/150056/reduce-resolution-of-asus-xtion-pro-live/) by [Andrew.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/5270/andrew.a/) on ROS Answers with karma: 324 on 2014-04-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As seen on the [dynamic_reconfigure documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure#dynamic_reconfigure.2BAC8-groovy.dynparam_command-line_tool), there is a node called `dynparam` that is part of the package that can be used to set reconfigurable parameters via the commandline. So for your situation a command like

```
rosrun dynamic_reconfigure dynparam set /camera/driver depth_mode 5
```

Would do what you want. In a launch file:

```
<launch>
<include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/openni.launch"/>
<node pkg="dynamic_reconfigure" type="dynparam" name="reconfig"
  output="screen" args="set /camera/driver depth_mode 5" />
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2014-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andrew.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/5270/andrew.a/) on 2014-04-08**:
The command line works great! But I'm having trouble with editing the launch file. I'm trying to edit the openni.launch file directly, at `/opt/ros/groovy/share/openni_launch/launch/openni.launch`. I got the error `maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`.

**Comment by [Andrew.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/5270/andrew.a/) on 2014-04-08**:
When I removed the `<node>` element completely, it worked! I just had to restart my mjpeg_server. Thank you!